# Meaning of "Whose husband only knows her not a whore"

Tags: meaning, lord-byron, don-juan

From Byron's *Don Juan*:

> Oh beautiful! and rare as beautiful
>        But theirs was love in which the mind delights
>   To lose itself when the old world grows dull,
>        And we are sick of its hack sounds and sights,
>   Intrigues, adventures of the common school,
>        Its petty passions, marriages, and flights,
>   Where Hymen's torch but brands one strumpet more,
>   **Whose husband only knows her not a wh-re.**

Just to make sure: is the meaning here "only her husband *thinks* that she is not a whore, but all the rest *know* that she is"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm tempted to say this belongs on ELU, but ...

Almost. It's not clear *what* the husband thinks, but I'd say it's implied that he's blissfully ignorant.

A more prosaic rendering would be *“it's only [her] husband who doesn't know that she is a wh-re”*.

Comment: Thank you, Will! I established an account here exactly because my questions are sometimes closevoted and downvoted on ELU and ELL SEs.